# What can my Shimano BR-M445 caliper be replaced with?

Tags: shimano, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

I have a Shimano BR-M445 disc brake caliper that has decided to give up on life, so I need a replacement. It seems like the BR-M445 is no longer produced, so are there other calipers that can replace it?

Comment: All Shimano/Tektro hydraulic levers and calipers are probably cross-compatible, there are numerous examples in the net of people using various combinations successfully.

Comment: Specifically I don't know, but do make sure your new caliper is as good or better than your old one.  If the old one has a fixed pad and only moves the other, then a two-sided caliper will be a huge improvement.  Likewise upgrading from 2pot to 4pot.  You've got the sunk cost of a new caliper, so the difference in price is your upgrade cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the BR-M445 and BR-M446 are the same/interchangeable, while the BR-M447 uses some different parts, but still has the same hose, so I assume that it is compatible as well.